# Is keeping version number in url a best way to handle multiple versions of url?

Tags: url

We are adding version in the url for making our application backward compatible.

We have an url version:    `{mysite}.com/v1/author/id`

May be in the next version of the app we may use something like this - `{mysite}.com/v2/contributors/author/id`

In order to support old url format in the new app, we are adding version in the url. By using the version in the path, we will know the url format and handle accordingly.

**Is this the best way to do this or is there any other recommend approach for this?**

Comment: You can use this approach for your API's (versioning) or you can just change the schema every time you add a new field o deprecate an old one by changing from (required field to optional field). In the scenario that you presented, you will need to create a new api, because you are not using the same pathname anymore, the version does not matter, you can start from v1.

Comment: Is not clear if you are talking about API version or front-end code version. For API this is a well know standard, many REST APIs systems (like WSO2) do this natively.

Comment: Its about API versioning, whenever there is a change in my route path. i will increment the version. i could support old url as well by using the version from url. @keul

Answer (score 0):

I prefer React Router(Navigate to specific file/folders) on the version differentiation , if your both version is managed in same repository.

Comment: could u please ellaborate? To be specific my requirement here is not about sub directories. the above mentioned route path is not folder structure but just route params

Comment: I tend to design my pages and apps in such a way that they are not affected by external requirements(such as versions mapping v1 or v2), consider you have V1, V2 and n.. apps, you dont want your routes to change n time, through React-Router you can make your versioning dynamic.